# how to use models in templates in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I create a simple search box in my site that use autocomplete with JQUERY that when user press ENTER page redirecting to the search page results

here is my section of template:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Search </label>
    <input id="tags" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) findAndSend(document.getElementById('tags').value)" />
</div>
```

and here is section of my javascript codes in the same file:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "suggest1",
      "suggest2",
      "suggest3",
      "suggest4",
      "suggest5"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
function findAndSend(value){
    window.location.assign("/"+value);
}
</script>
```

I want to use database models.py file for suggestions (`suggest1` , `suggest2` , ...).I need a way to import models.py in my template.Am I wrong ? please help me.thanks

Comment: maybe use ajax to get suggestions?

Comment: how to do this with ajax ?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSNciGr8kY i dont watched it (just googled). https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoCompleteSolutions "official site" has few links for reusable solutions.

Comment: thanks I will watch it

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoCompleteSolutions
There is few links for reusable solutions.